# Android Recyclerview item selection get lost when scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have radio buttons in recyclerview about 50 to 100 radio button which losses checked when scrolling the recyclerview

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of the recycler view is that items are as you scroll. If an items goes too far off screen its view is repurposed for the next item scrolling onto the screen. Any state you want maintained must be saved elsewhere and reapplied to your viewholder in `onCreateViewHolder`.

So you have to store the selected state, maybe a variable in your adapter, for which item is selected, and then in your `onCreateViewHolder` you need to check whether that item is the checked one or not and check/uncheck the box accordingly.

Remember, if you don't programmatically uncheck the boxes in `onCreateViewHolder` then you might end up seeing the wrong items checked when previous views get recycled for new items.

Answer (score 0):

Just override `getItemId` and `getItemViewType` in your adapter.

```
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long { 
    return position.toLong()
} 

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return position
}
```